# Strange "dancing" effect in a wpf datagrid with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

[image: Disco effect in wpf datagrid]

To reproduce: wpf datagrid - make sure size of the datagrid is such that horizontal scroll bar is visible and choose a datagridtextcolumn of a particular size - now try to enter a text which straddles this size :)

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, can you post a working example?

Comment: This is autoSize issue. just make some size for you columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about disabling the `ScrollBar` when cells are being edited? Maybe you can add a handler to the `DataGrid.BeginningEdit` event and disable the `ScrollBar` there?

```
ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(dataGrid, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(dataGrid, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```